# log4net is logging all levels, instead of what I've configured it to do

Tags: c#, .net, logging, configuration, log4net

I have the level set to "INFO" but I'm seeing DEBUG events in the log.

#### Config

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net"/>
    </configSections>

    <log4net>
        <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
            <level value="INFO"/>
            <file value="Logs\Log.txt" />
            <appendToFile value="true" />
            <rollingStyle value="Size" />
            <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
            <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
            <staticLogFileName value="true" />
            <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
                <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
            </layout>
        </appender>

        <root>
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
        </root>
    </log4net>
</configuration>
```

#### Code

```
private ILog Log { get; set; }

static Program()
{
    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    //...
    this.Log.Info("Started in RunOnce mode.");
}
```

Comment: I would check the configuration actually gets loaded.

Comment: It does since the log file is actually getting used...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that within your root tag you need to set the property `<level value="INFO">` for your appender.

Comment: Correct - but to be more precise, the `<root>` element describes a _logger_, not an _appender_. And that is the entire point; the logging levels are specified on the loggers, not on the appenders.

Answer (score 1):

have a look at

http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Core.Level.html

It looks like this could be the cuplrit

> When logging at level INFO the actual
>   level used is not Info but the value
>   of LoggerRepository.LevelMap["INFO"].
>   The default value for this is Info,
>   but this can be changed by
>   reconfiguring the level map

Answer (score 0):

I typically declare/initialize my ILog with:

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

and then define the logger in the web config: (include full namespace of Program)

```
<logger name="Program">
  <level value="Info"/>
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</logger>
```